# What is the difference between OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter and OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter

Tags: spring-security

What is the difference between:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter
```

which seems to be created by the `httpSecurity.oauth2Login()` DSL and

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter
```

which seems to be created by the `httpSecurity.oauth2Client()` DSL.

They both seems to be doing very similar processing but the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter`
produces `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` based on `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken`.

`OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter` does something similar but seems to save `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` and then redirect to original request or configured request.

I tried to understand but it is still not clear. Can someone explain in details?

Answer (score 0):

`OAuth2Login` DSL configures an external login provider that specifically listens to specific URL pattern for OAuth2 login providers like 'GitHub' & `Google`. But with `OAuth2Client` you are configuring a client that needs to do a perform authorization grant flow with an external custom Oauth2 server.

Please note with OAuth2Login DSL you are basically configuring an external identity provider for spring security - login mechanism while with OAuth2Client you are configuring your application as a valid registered OAuth2 Client.

From a perspective, their use cases are overlapping yet they are different purpose.